# how to dynamically load pyinstaller executable to my python code

Tags: python, python-3.x, software-recommendation, pyinstaller

how to dynamically load pyinstaller executable

I am restructuring my application, I want to give more developers the ability to contribute to the application development by allowing them to inject their functions and "algorithms" into my application. I am looking more for something like the dll in c++ but in Python.

I am wondering if it is possible to use the pyinstaller to build an executable that can be imported to my master application. Are there any other alternatives that I can look at?

I want to import a specific function called run function from inside the main.py script.
my question is how exactly to do this?